# Summarize 2 sets into 1 set per user KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel

What would be the proper way to summarize 2 sets into 1 set by user?

For example, in the picture below:

[image]

I want to create a new set (the column that has the question mark) combining the X_locations and Y_Locations columns by User.

I did try strcat_array, but I am not sure those results will work, is anyone aware of a proper way to do this?, I envision something like this?:

```
| summarize whateverSetUnionFunctionHere(X_Locations,Y_Locations) by User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the combination of @Avnera & @Yoni K. answers

```
datatable(User:string, X_locations:dynamic, Y_locations:dynamic)
[
    "user1", dynamic(["a"]), dynamic(["a"]),
    "user2", dynamic(["b","c"]), dynamic(["c"]),
    "user2", dynamic(["b"]), dynamic(["b","d"]),
]
| summarize make_set(set_union(X_locations, Y_locations)) by User
```

| User | set_ |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | ["a"] |
| user2 | ["b","c","d"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/dumarkovdev.westeurope/databases/mydb?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjdDi1CKr4pKizLx0HYWI%20Jz85MSSzPy8YquUyrzE3MxkHYVITEFNXq5oXi4FIFAqBeo3VNJRgMpoRCslKsVqYvCRVBuhqE5S0lFKRtORTEAHqmqQCSkQHbG8XDUKxaW5uYlFmVWpCrmJ2anxxaklGkAcX5oH9IEGkg9RfKapqZBUqQAKDABXEU3KGwEAAA==)

P.S.
There are multiple variations for that, E.g. `set_union` could be replaced by `array_concat`

Comment: Thank you @David, set_union() it is, of course! it is literally in the name of the function :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [make_set()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction) function, it will create a distinct set from all the sets in the input.

Comment: thank you @Avnera, I thought about that originally, but It seems I can't pass 2 sets into the make_set() function, I need to be able to somehow combine the 2 columns by User

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`set_union()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/setunionfunction) function.

For example:

```
datatable(User:string, X_locations:dynamic, Y_locations:dynamic)
[
    "user1", dynamic(["a"]), dynamic(["a"]),
    "user2", dynamic(["b"]), dynamic(["c"]),
    "user2", dynamic(["b"]), dynamic(["b"]),
]
| extend result = set_union(X_locations, Y_locations)
```

| User | X_locations | Y_locations | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | [ "a" ] | [ "a" ] | [ "a" ] |
| user2 | [ "b" ] | [ "c" ] | [ "b", "c" ] |
| user2 | [ "b" ] | [ "b" ] | [ "b" ] |